# How can I build asm.jar with debug information?

Tags: java

The org.objectweb.asm library that downloaded from mavenrepository doesn't contain the debug information, it's so hard to put a break point and also when generate override method from intellij, the arguments are all nonsense single char names. I tried to put `product.noshrink` in the `build.properties`, but it doesn't seem to do the work.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source from here and then compile with whatever options you want. http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=23